# Meter -- Change colours

Tags: html

Edit: the code has been changed to my answer.

---

Is it possible to change the 'grey' background colour in the meter?

I can change the 'progress bar' colour to red, but cannot change the 'grey background colour'.

I would like to have the meter display two colours, red and blue. Is this possible?

Many thanks,

```
/* Changes the 'progress bar' colour */
meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
    background: none; /* Required to get rid of the default background property */
    background: red;
}

/* Changes the 'background' colour */
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
    background: blue;
}
```

---

```
<meter value="0.3"></meter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check once. Hope it helps.

```css
meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: none; /* Required to get rid of the default background property */
  background-color: whiteSmoke;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #333 inset;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #999 inset;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg, 
    #8bcf69 5%, 
    #e6d450 5%,
    #e6d450 15%,
    #f28f68 15%,
    #f28f68 55%,
    #cf82bf 55%,
    #cf82bf 95%,
    #719fd1 95%,
    #719fd1 100%
  );
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<meter max="120" value="55.93" title="GB"></meter>
```

Comment: Thanks. Got an answer from this.

Comment: Mark an answer if it helps.